# how to persist a composite pattern with nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, data-modeling, composite

I am looking for examples of how to persist a tree structure, ideally one used as part of a composite pattern. Gabriel Shenker apparently wrote something about this awhile back but the [link is dead](http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate.aspx).

Just by way of example, below is a composition of GeographicBoundaries, which in the USA might see a country composed of states and zip codes, states made up of cities, etc. Any whole part example will do of course tho.

Cheers,
Berryl

[image]